# Overlay view on top of root view from child?

Tags: swiftui

I want to display a bottom sheet or modal view from a child view, but should overlay on top of the whole app, even if there's a tab or nav bar. For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selected) {
            Content1View()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "1.circle")
                    Text("First")
                }
                .tag(0)
        }
    }
}

struct Content1View: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Content 1")
            .overlay(
                Color.blue
                    .opacity(0.1)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            )
    }
}
```

How can I make the blue color overlay on top of the whole app without making the tab bar do it?

Comment: hi dear friend, can you find any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a bottom sheet, the [.sheet modifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/sheet(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) actually does this, even with a tab or nav bar:

```
struct Content1View: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { showSheet = true}) {
            Text("Content 1")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Color.blue
                .opacity(0.1)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```

[.fullScreenCover](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/button/fullscreencover(ispresented:ondismiss:content:)) works the same way, but covers the whole screen:

```
struct Content1View: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { showSheet = true}) {
            Text("Content 1")
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Color.blue
                .opacity(0.1)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
}
```